# Error java.sql.sqlexception no suitable driver found for jdbc sqldeveloper

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Me podrían ayudar con este error?

[image: les adjunto esa imagen, es el error que me da a la hora de logearme]

Tengo una base de datos en sql developer, la he creado con una tabla que incluye usuarios y contraseñas. Cree un programa con un login, he programado el botón, he creado mi clase conexión y he importado la librería jdbc.

//esta es mi clase de conexion, si, al parecer si se denota que no e importado la jdbc pero lo he echo. gracias por sus respuestas. 
y perdon por la molestia...

public class Conexion {
    public String user = "sa";
    public String password = "123";
  // 
    public String url="jdbc:sqldeveloper://localhost:1521;databaseName=xe";

```
public Connection conection =null;
public Statement state = null;

public Statement Conectar ()
{ 
    try
    {
       Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password) ;
       cn.close();
       state = conection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY );
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    return state;

}
```

Comment: Saludos Nenton, bienvenido a SO en Español, debes evitar colocar imágenes de mensajes de error, en su lugar agrega el mensaje (esto va a aumentar mucho las probabilidades de recibir una respuesta que te ayude con tu pregunta.

Comment: Realiza el [tour] para que sepas como funciona el sitio y además [answer] para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida.

Answer (score 1):

Te falta añadir el `jar` con el driver de `sql server` para java a tu proyecto. Puedes encontrarlo [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server)

[Aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-java#step-1--connect) tienes la documentación oficial de Microsoft con ejemplos.

Comment: te comento. estoy trabajando con sqldeveloper. y el jar ya lo he añadido. gracias por el segundo link.